# Clear element content

Tags: javascript

So, I still making a system when you press a button the system will get all items from a json file.

I do the system for write content on screen (write the tags and other things)

the code I used for for write content on "div":

```js
function update()
  {
  for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) 
    {
    var obj = database[i];
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<a href=" 
        + obj.link 
        + " class=" 
        + "a" + ">" 
        + obj.title 
        + "</a> <br class=" + "br" + ">";
    console.log(i);
    };
  };
```

And I create another function to clear the div, but It don't work, I tryied get element inside div using getElement().

I don't know what I do now, if anyone can help me I will be pretty happy =)

thx

OBS: I new at javascript programming, and sorry about my english '-'

Answer (score 0):

You can clear element content in the same way as you set it:

```js
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: this method remove the tag from element?

Comment: Try it, it should remove all child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Element.innerHTML = "SOME NEW HTML CONTENT"` to completely update that element's HTML with new content:

```js
const EL_main = document.querySelector('#main');
const EL_load = document.querySelector('#load');

const fetchDatabase = () => Array.from({length: 20}).map(_ => {
  const rand = ~~(Math.random() * 1e4);
  return {link: `http://${rand}.html`, title: `Page ${rand}`}
});


function update() {
  const database = fetchDatabase();
  EL_main.innerHTML = database.reduce((acc, item) => acc + `
    <a href="${item.href}">${item.title}</a><br>
  `, "");
};

update();
EL_load.addEventListener("click", update);
```

```html
<button id="load">Load new content</button>
<div id="main"></div>
```